# How to configure a fallback in Logtash if Elasticsearch is disconnected?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, fallback

We are going to deploy an Elasticsearch in a VM and configure our Logstash output to point to it. We don't plan for a multiple node cluster or cloud for hosting Elasticsearch. But we are checking for any possibility to fallback to our system-locally run Elasticsearch service, in case of any connection failure to the VM hosted Elasticsearch.

Is it possible to configure in Logstash in any way to have such fallback, in case connection to Elasticsearch is not available.

We use 5.6.5 version of Logstash and Elasticsearch. Thanks!

Comment: why not creating just a cluster of Elasticsearch servers like is recommended here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_add_failover.html?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I will check if it is feasible for our environment/cost.

Comment: @heroin One naive question. Is it possible to have a two node cluster of Elasticsearch, one running at VM and another running locally in the same system of Logstash? So in case any connection failure to VM it can fallback to local?

Comment: The Es nodes can be anywhere as long as they are part of the same cluster. Then in your logstash config, you put both nodes in your elasticsearch `hosts` setting, if one is not reachable, the second will take over

Comment: There could be issues when ES cluster has nodes in different DC (like local and remote in the question). See https://www.elastic.co/blog/clustering_across_multiple_data_centers .

Comment: Naive answer here: create a file output that you regularly archive/delete. I know it's dumb, but if nothing else works...

Comment: @heroin It is really a good source of information regarding clustering across multiple data centers. Thanks! I may go with the passive backup cluster considering the drawbacks in the distributed cluster.